# How to safely kill Linux process?

Tags: linux, signals, sigterm

An embedded Linux system that continuously writes files (~1/s) to a FAT32 partition occasionally corrupts the partition when interrupted. The process can be interrupted 2 ways: a power cycle, or using musb_hdrc/gadget to copy files to and from the host via USB. The musb_hdrc/gadget is used to switch access to the partition from internal embedded control to  USB for transferring files to and from an external host. The solution may be to do a `killall process-name` but will this safely kill the Linux process? IOW: will the process complete any file IO already started or will there still be corrupted partitions? According to the [killall  man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) `If no signal name is specified SIGTERM is sent.` Does something need to be added to the code to make sure the kill is clean and/or is there a special killall signal name to do a clean kill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can modify your application to catch any signal except SIGKILL.
Shutdown operation or cleanup can be performed in a signal handler
Here is a simple example of setting up a handler to delete temporary files when certain fatal signals happen:

```
#include <signal.h>

 void
 termination_handler (int signum)
 {
   printf ("Caught signal %d\n", sig);
   switch(signum)
   {
       case SIGINT:
       printf ("CTRL C not allowed\n");
       break;

       case SIGTERM:
       struct temp_file *p;
       for (p = temp_file_list; p; p = p->next)
           unlink (p->name);
       exit(1);
       break;

       default:
   ...
   }
 }

 int
 main (void)
 {
   ...
   if (signal (SIGINT, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
     signal (SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
   if (signal (SIGHUP, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
     signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
   if (signal (SIGTERM, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
     signal (SIGTERM, SIG_IGN);
   ...
 }
```

Code after signal handler will not execute in case of SIGTERM.

Comment: Added something similar to your example to my code. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

If the code is well written, the process should catch the `SIGTERM` and cleanly stop what it is doing and cleanly close every open resource.

If you can't modify the code, and you already observed that a `SIGTERM` signal brutally stops the process (just like a `SIGKILL`), i guess there's nothing you can do to stop it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo bugs, there is no partition (and filesystem) corruption possible as a consequence of killing a process that does a regular file I/O (i.e. does not work with partition as a device, manipulating raw blocks).

If the process doesn't care to handle or ignore signals, `SIGTERM` will kill it in just the same merciless manner as `SIGKILL` would. For processes that actually try to exit gracefully on signals, `SIGTERM` means *would you please shut down*, while `SIGKILL` just kills (it's impossible to catch it).